# neo4j-ogm returns null bookmark when executed in transaction/concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j, transactions, neo4j-ogm

**Scenario 1:**

When I execute the following code without opening a transaction, it returns bookmark successfully.

```
    Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session2.query("MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)", new HashMap<>());
    String lastBookmark = session2.getLastBookmark();
    System.out.println("WITHOUT" + " - " + lastBookmark);
```

Output:

```
WITHOUT - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
```

When I acquire a transaction explicitly, getLastBookmark() returns null.

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction(Transaction.Type.READ_ONLY);
    session.query("MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)", new HashMap<>());
    System.out.println("With" + " - " + session.getLastBookmark());
    session.getTransaction().close();
```

Output:

```
With - null
```

This always happens irrespective of single or multiple threads.

**Scenario 2:**

Even without transaction when I try to execute getLastBookmark() from multiple threads, it returns null intermittently.

```
      Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.query("MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)", new HashMap<>());
            String lastBookmark = session.getLastBookmark();
            System.out.println("lastBookmark" + " - " + lastBookmark);
            if (lastBookmark == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(" lastBookmark NULL");
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.query("MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)", new HashMap<>());
            String lastBookmark = session.getLastBookmark();
            System.out.println("lastBookmark" + " - " + lastBookmark);
            if (lastBookmark == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(" lastBookmark NULL");
            }
        }
    });
```

Output:

```
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - null
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException:  lastBookmark NULL
    at MyTest.lambda$testSession$4(MyTest.java:173)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
lastBookmark - neo4j:bookmark:v1:tx6776
```

Any ideas?

I am using neo4j-ogm-core:2.1.5 & neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:2.1.5 dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bookmarks are tied to transactions. They are sent by the database at the end of transactions.

When you use `query` without opening a transaction before, an autocommit transaction is managed by OGM (it is an implicit transaction). The bookmark is available right after executing the `query` method.

When managing yourself the transaction (explicit transaction), you have to wait the end of the transaction for the bookmark to be available.

Regarding your second point, try updating driver and/or OGM. If the problem is still there, share a sample project reproducing the issue (you can use some templates [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template)), preferably in another question for clarity.

Comment: yes, by committing transaction I am getting bookmark in scenario 1. Problem described in scenario 2 still exists after updating dependencies.